# go to url from php and execute the remaining code

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This php code is executed using ajax. Ajax request does not coming back after executing header statement.

```
if(is_numeric($phone) && strlen($phone)==10){
        $text = "Hi $name, your account created at hhhhh. Check your email to get updates. Thank you";
        $sms = "http://domain.com/msg.php?user=******&pass=*****&sender=***&phone=$phone&text=$text&priority=****&stype=***";
header("Location: $sms");
    }

    $url = "done";
    echo $url;
```

What I need is that, just go to `$sms` url in php and execute the remaining section when calling this code through ajax. Is there any other method than header to go to a link and execute the remaining code in php.

Comment: Do some research about [curl](https://www.google.com/search?q=php%20curl)

Comment: Why are you sending a password through a GET request?

Comment: Sms gateway api is like this.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
 header("Location: $sms");
```

with

```
 @file_get_contents($sms);
```

Comment: Tried this, the code is executing completely, but not getting sms.

Answer (score 0):

You can't tell the browser that it should display content from a different URL **and** display content from the current URL at the same time.

It sounds like you should be making an HTTP request to the `domain.com` URL from your server, in which case you should be looking at [cURL](http://php.net/curl) rather than `header()`.

Comment: Tried this code
`$curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_URL => $sms,
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'SMS'
        ));
        $resp = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);`
code executing with no error, but not getting sms.